Как открыть папку, но без ShellExecute?
Как показать папку в проводнике?
ShellExecute(0,'open','explorer.exe',PChar('"'+txtFolder+'"'),nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Нет, вариант с ShellExecute не подходит.
Потому что лично я использую модификацию (QTTabBar), которая добавляет вкладки для встроенного проводника Windows. И вместо того, чтобы открыть новую вкладку в уже открытом окне, запуск "explorer.exe", ожидаемо, открывает новое окно с новой вкладкой в нём.
Однако я знаю, что это возможно, потому что так можно сделать в python:
import os
os.startfile(txtFolder)
#subprocess.Popen(f'explorer "{txtFolder}"') #Аналог ShellExecute.

Этот код вместо открытия нового окна, открывает новую вкладку в текущем окне проводника. То, что и нужно.
Как сделать то же самое на Delphi? Какой есть аналог os.startfile для Delphi?

Вы запускаете программу (explorer) и передаете её параметры командной строки с именем папки. Если вместо имени программы передадите имя папки, то не сработает ли так, как вам нужно?

Вот так? ShellExecute(0,'open',PChar(txtFolder),'',nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL); Нет, это не помогает, новое окно всё равно открывается.
Однако... разница есть. Если эта папка уже открыта в активной вкладке в другом окне, то оно просто переключает фокус на это окно без открытия нового.
В общем, лучше не стало.

А вот так ShellExecute(0, 'explore', PChar(txtFolder), '', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);? Ну и вот это почитать.

@Alekcvp Тоже самое, как и предыдущий вариант.

Ну тогда остался последний вариант ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(txtFolder), '', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);, хотя в доках написано что это то же самое. Или дело в самом QTTabBar.

Функция os.startfile под капотом использует ShellExecute, так что весь вопрос, с какими параметрами её вызывать.

Ничего не приходит в голову, кроме, как открыть через TFileOpenDialog:
procedure TForm1.OpenDialog(aPath: String);
begin
  with TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil) do
  try
    DefaultFolder := aPath;
    Options := [fdoPickFolders ];
    if Execute then
      ShowMessage(FileName);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

И соотвеетсвенно вызов:
OpenDialog('C:\Windows\System32\');

